# Android: Add to favorites option in android app that links to a ListView

Tags: android, listview, bookmarks

I have loads of HTML pages, and when users click a certain button, one of the HTML pages open, I have also created a ListView sort of like an Index page, now I already added a Bookmark / Add to Favorites button to the layout of the WebView, I want it that when the Bookmark button is clicked, it adds the current page to "Bookmark" which can be accessed from the main activity.

Main Activity - User Select Page - Page Opens - User Click Bookmark Button on Page - Page is Added to Bookmark

The "Favorites" activity has a ListView layout, How do I make this work?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that. You can store this information in database, in preferences, in files or even on remote server. Have you already tried something?

Comment: Nope, I dont know the best way for it, I want it local, so it can be assesed without internet. I read about sql. What would you prefer though and how do I go about it? thanks

Comment: It depends on your task. In common case, you have sqlite database with your data. You show data in listview from this database and mark as favorite some items (which have true in database column). If you have a little set of data you can store information which items are favorites in preferences.

Comment: I have this items in a ListView already in the index activity. Is it possible so when one add a webpage to the bookmarks tab, it shows in the favorite activity with a ListView layout, and when the user clicks on the "bookmarked item" it links to Indexpage listview and open the webpage out. Can that work?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest Practice is to add a boolean to your DTO.
call it something like favorite.
when the user clicks the bookmark/favorite button call the setFavorite method and set it to true.
and at the beginning of your FavoritesActivity check for those items in your list that have the isFavorite set to true.
Store them is another List and feed that List to your ListView's Adapter.